# ExtJS pdf.js panel for viewing PDF

Tags: extjs, pdf.js

I've used https://github.com/SunboX/ext_ux_pdf_panel to view PDF files in my project. However, it doesn't seem to work with locked PDF files. I've looked around for over 3 hours now with no success. Anyone with an idea of what I need to do to get it to render locked PDF files? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Building a new pdf.js from the latest source sorted out my issue. The rendering is slower, though.